# BitTorrent Sync: minimum peer number

Tags: bittorrent, bittorrent-sync

Is BitTorrent Sync any faster than Dropbox if you only use 2 computers? Does the speed increase if you have more computers to share the file with (faster than a centralized syncing system such as Dropbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P2P sync tools are synchronous. Systems relying on a server support asynchronous transfer. So they will have different performance characteristics under different conditions.

So if the two clients are never online at the same time their effective transfer speed would be zero in a P2P setting.

On the other hand the server in a centralized solution might throttle transfers and has to traverse the internet where a P2P solution might be able to exploit a local network if they're on the same LAN.